# Why are the limit points of $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ equal to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why are the limit points of $\mathbb R $ \ $\mathbb Q $ equal to  $\mathbb R $ ? If you find a very small neighborhood centered in a Real number, isn't it possible that that neighborhood only intersects the $\mathbb Q $ numbers and not any other irrational number except itself? I thought that the answer would be  $\mathbb Q $ and I understand why those have to be limit points. I just don't understand why the rest of $\mathbb R $ set are too.
In addition, can anyone give me an example of a set which doesn't contain it's own limit points?

Comment: You've evidently seen a proof that every real number is a limit point. That proof _shows_ that the answer to your question "Isn't it possible that...?" is no.

Answer (score 1):

For the rest of $\mathbb R$ ($r$ irrational) consider $r\in \mathbb R, q (\neq 0)\in \mathbb Q, n\in \mathbb N$ then $r+\frac q{2^n}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

> If you find a very small neighborhood centered in a Real number, isn't it possible that that neighborhood only intersects the $\mathbb Q $ numbers and not any other irrational number except itself?

No, this is not possible. Between any two rational numbers $x_1, x_2$ there is always a real number which is irrational. For example, let's choose a sequence $(a_n)$ with rational terms which tends to $\pi$ (this can be done because $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$), then for sufficiently large $n$, we get that the ratio $\pi/a_n$ gets arbitrarily close to $1$. Then we will have
$$x_1<\frac12(x_1+x_2)\left(\frac{\pi}{a_n}\right)<x_2$$
where the middle number is obviously irrational. Of course this construction is quite arbitrary, and you can do the same with any irrational number other than $\pi$, say $\sqrt 2$.

Now, we want to show that the set of limit points of $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb R$, which is the same as showing that for any real number $x$ there is a sequence $(x_n)$ of irrational numbers that tends to $x$. This is quite easily done: for example, when $x$ is irrational just pick $x_n=x+1/n$, and when $x$ is rational, pick $x_n=x+\pi/n$. (You can use your favourite irrational number other than $\pi$, of course).

For the last part of your question: the set of limit points of $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb R$, which is a fact you've probably learnt. But of course not every real number is rational.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. So, if $x\in \mathbb Q$, there is a sequence of $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ that converges to $x$.